# Can Cargo.toml have Cargo tell rustc to include plugins?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Let's say I want to lint all my code by rust-clippy. For now, I'll have to write

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#![plugin(clippy)]
```

in each of my sources. Can I somehow configure Cargo to have rustc use the plugin without needing to add it to my source file? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to do this with `cargo` (without editing source), but it's definitely something I'd like too. The use case I can imagine is that some users wish to outlaw certain patterns in all dependencies, e.g. maybe outlaw `unsafe` code that's not in a white list of crates, or even go further by requiring any `unsafe` is [verified](https://github.com/kmcallister/launch-code).

The compiler has partial support for this in the form of `rustc -Z extra-plugins=...`, but Cargo doesn't expose anything like it externally yet.

I opened [#1579](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1579).

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps I should have opened an issue myself, but I was unsure if not exposing it was a deliberate decision.

Answer (score 1):

No, you must specify the macro in the source code.